# subprojects dependencies failure with Gradle

Tags: gradle, dependency-management, multi-module, multi-project

I'm struggling with Gradle and the build configuration of the following project structure (pretty simple...):

```
/projA
   /projB
   /projC
```

projC using classes from projB.

In projA/settings.gradle:

```
include 'projB'
include 'projC'
```

In projC/build.gradle:

```
dependencies{
 compile project(':projB')
}
```

In IntelliJ I have no problem of dependency resolution, but when I'm running a ./gradlew build in projA, I'm facing a compilation error:

```
ClassC: Unresolved reference: ClassB
```

(where ClassC is the class of projC which is failing on the use of ClassB which is a class from projB, obviously...)

Notice that the code is in Kotlin language, that I do not have any problem to run the app in IntelliJ (spring boot run), but any build with Gradle give me an error (both in Intellij and command line).

What am I missing?

Regards,
Adrien

Answer (score 0):

It's a common Gradle idiom to have an additional top level directory for your `rootProject`. That's a special project that's the parent to all other projects in your build, in a [multi-project build](https://guides.gradle.org/creating-multi-project-builds/).

That's where your `settings.gradle` file goes:

```
include ':projA:projB'
include ':projA:projC'
```

Then, I'd recommend having projA as a subdirectory of your rootProject, so your hierarchy would look as follows:

```
/myProject
  settings.gradle
  /projA
    build.gradle
    /projB
      build.gradle
    /projC
      build.gradle
```

Also, in `projC/build.gradle`, you'll want instead:

```
dependencies {
  compile project(':projA:projB')
}
```

That should do it.

Comment: Thanks Felipe, staying with my first project hierarchy (projA as parent of projB and projC), `compile project(":projB")` in build.gradle on my projC won't do the job? why do I need to add an additional top level since projA is already a toplevel project acting as parent project?

Comment: AFAIK Gradle will want you to provide the "full path" to your project dependencies, that's why you need `":projA:projB"`, think of it as a  relative path to a directory.